# responsive SVG viewBox preserveAspectRatio:"none" and viewBox scaled to percentages

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I'm trying to make an responsive SVG viewBox using preserveAspectRatio:"none", but the elements aren't being positioned as I expected.

The border responds to the aspect ratio of the viewBox, but the elements are being positioned as if the viewBox aspect ratio is always 1.

I expected these elements to be positioned in the corners of the viewBox:

```css
    .container {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:flex;
    justify-items:center;
    align-items:top;    

    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 180vh;

    border-style:dotted;
    border-color:gold;
  
    }
    #svgOuter {
      border: 10px dashed #d9d9d9;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg id="svgOuter" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio:"none">
     
        <rect id="rect1" fill="silver" height="20" width="20" transform="translate(100 100)" />
        <rect id="rect2" fill="silver" height="20" width="20"  transform="translate(900 100)" />
        <rect id="rect3" fill="silver" height="20" width="20"  transform="translate(100 900)" />
        <rect id="rect4" fill="silver" height="20" width="20"  transform="translate(900 900)" />
    
        <rect id="rect11" fill="gold" height="15" width="15" x="100" y="100"/>
        <rect id="rect12" fill="gold" height="15" width="15" x="900" y="100"/>
        <rect id="rect13" fill="gold" height="15" width="15" x="100" y="900"/>
        <rect id="rect14" fill="gold" height="15" width="15" x="900" y="900"/>
    
        <rect id="rect21" fill="cadetblue" height="10" width="10" x="10%" y="10%"/>
        <rect id="rect22" fill="cadetblue" height="10" width="10" x="90%" y="10%"/>
        <rect id="rect23" fill="cadetblue" height="10" width="10" x="10%" y="90%"/>
        <rect id="rect24" fill="cadetblue" height="10" width="10" x="90%" y="90%"/>
    </div>
```

I've tried absolute unites, percentages, and transform translate.  I also tried applying each of these     styles with CSS.

Also, Ctrl-k does not format code for me in Firefox.  Ctrl-k toggles single quotes, it does not indent 4 spaces.

Comment: Typo: Use `preserveAspectRatio="none"` instead of preserveAspectRatio:"none"